# ssh rsa keys expires after 5 years

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I'm using an old login with ssh-rsa public/private key and all was good.
I noticed that a couple of days ago the authorizazion was avoid with message "server refused our keys". After diggin' I figured out that the couple of keys stop working after exactly 5 years of their creation.
So I make a new pair of keys, take the public one, paste inside a file in ~/.ssh of the username that I'm using, converted it with `ssh-keygen -if` and paste the new file into `authorized_keys` but the I still get "server refused our key".

It's ok to copy and paste the real key without transfer it?

What I'm missing? This isn't my first time using a pair of keys and I follow the same procedure as described. I'm in doubt if I'm changing the correct `authorized_keys` file but I've take a look in `/etc/passwd` and see where is the home of the login which I'm using.

Comment: Did you remove the offending key on both sides? It's possible it never asks for the second after rejecting the first.

Comment: Yes I did, on the authorized_keys file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, its not nessessary to do the `ssh-keygen -if` on the remote machine. Just copy the public part of your keypair (e.g. id_rsa.pub) to the remote machine and append it to the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file.

There is also a neat utility that does it all for you: ssh-copy-id.

`ssh-copy-id [-i [identity_file]] [user@]machine`

Also make sure the key is loaded with `ssh-add -l`.

Comment: I never understand this. the id_rsa.pub or whatelse is still necessary after append the key to authorized_keys?

Comment: If you have appended the id_rsa.pub to authorized_keys on the remote machine, you can delete it on the remote machine. ssh-copy-id does this all for you.

Comment: Did you mean `ssh-add -l`?

Comment: I got it! Thanks, for some reaseon I was edited a wrong file. Btw the key aren't expired, was only a coincidence that they was created 5 years ago!